# Transforming a segment by bending to direction

Tags: c++, opengl, math, rendering

Im not sure how to approach this:
I need to "bend" a segment of length 1 with respect to a unit direction.
The strength of the bend is 1/y over the length of the segment.
The transform needs to be defined for every point on the segment and the length should be preserved.
The following i have in mind:
[image]

Comment: [Bézier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve), maybe? Try them [online](http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs424/notes2013/canvas/bezier.html).

Comment: How does the direction vector correlate with the bending? Should that be the tangent direction at the end of the bended segment?

Comment: Yes exactly, also its limited in its vertical component: y >= 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want to bend the segment so that it would have a constant curvature k, that is it's going to be an arc of length 1 of a circle of radius 1/k. Then the point (0, t) of the segment maps to the point:

```
(1 - cos(kt))/k    ,    sin(kt)/k
```

For small values of k (that is when the curvature is tiny and the segment is nearly straight), to prevent a division by zero accident, you map it by the following formula (which is the taylor expansion of the above near k=0):

```
  k t^2 / 2       ,      t - k^2 t^3 / 6
```

**EDIT:** Following your comment:

Assuming that your direction vector is (x,y), then the value of the corresponding curvature that will give that tangent vector at the end of the arc (t=1) is given by:

```
k = atan2(x, y)
```

Comment: thx, trying it out. This is exactly what I had in mind but couldn't figure out the details.